# How do I populate an XtraGrid dynamically?

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I have a grid that needs to show data from a large table. I don't want to load the whole table at once as that will be hard on memory. I'm aware that there is a virtual load on server mode but I'm loading from a local csv file and not using any sql server databases.

Are there any such methods for virtual loading to support custom data access objects so I can just grab data from my csv when the user scrolls down on the grid?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe any such thing exists. However, it's possible to roll your own by implementing the DevExpress.Data.IListServer interface. From what I've read on the subject, it doesn't appear to be a trivial task. These links might get you started.

[Simple IListServer implementation](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1307.aspx)

[Does the XtraGrid support Virtual Load mode?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A1022.aspx)

One alternative might be to import your csv data into a SQLite database. Then you could use a LinqServerModeSource as your data source. The following link provides details on how you might do that.

[SQLite and Server Mode](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q293056.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a brilliant help, thanks! I'll look into this straight away.

Comment: as @kenrogers pointed out, you'll need to use XPO. How large is the file (in terms of rows)?

Comment: Forgive me I've only just started with DevExpress, whats an XPO?
It could potentially be hundreds of thousands of rows and most likely run on quite old systems hence my need to limit the amount of memory the data is loaded into.

I must say I really dont want to stat messing around with implementing my own IListServer implementation. I did notice on one link it mentioned extending the virtualList in the DataVirtualGrid demo with a datatable but it was a bit vague about what to keep, change and what was unneccesary. In fact I cant find any docuentation on the DataVirtualGrid demo at all.

Comment: XPO stands for eXpress Persistent Objects. It's DevX's ORM library. You can use XPO, but you don't have to. As pointed out in the "SQLite and Server Mode" link, you can use XPO, or you can use LinqServerModeSource and a SQLite connector such as DbLinq. In order to use XPO, you must have purchased a license for it from DevExpress. So, if you don't have one, LINQ is your only option.